# HTML form to CSV and download CSV using PHP

Tags: php, csv

i can  input 
Here is my code to input data from HTML form to csv
Now how do I download the file
Here is my code

```
<?$FirstName=$_POST['FirstName'];
$LastName=$_POST['LastName'];
$DOB=$_POST['DOB'];
$data=$FirstName.",".$LastName.",".$DOB;
$file="test.csv"; 
file_put_contents($file, $data . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND); 
Need the code to download the data on my local machine
?>
```

Comment: **<?** ? Why not `<?php `?

Comment: It was a typo sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you use the header `Content-Disposition` set to `attachment` you can download the POSTed form contents as you are hoping to do.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $str=implode( ',', $_POST );
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=mycsv.csv');
        exit( $str );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <input type='text' name='firstname' value='geronimo' />
            <input type='text' name='lastname' value='bogtrotter' />
            <input type='text' name='dob' value='15.6.1851' />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

> .... When used in combination with Content-Disposition: attachment, it
>   is used as the default filename for an eventual "Save As" dialog
>   presented to the user.

To update an existing csv file is a little different - the form is the same but the processing of the submitted data requires a different approach. In Google Chrome ( not tested in other browsers ) there is no `save-as` dialogue displayed so subsequent calls to this script will generate numerically indexed versions but with amended content.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if( !empty( $_POST ) ){

            $str=implode( ',', $_POST );
            $file='mycsv.csv';
            $bytes=file_put_contents( $file, $str . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );

            if( $bytes ){
                http_response_code( 200 );
                header('Content-Type: text/csv');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.csv"');

                if( $fh = @fopen( $file, 'rb' ) ) {
                    while( !@feof( $fh ) and ( connection_status()==0 ) ) {
                        print( fread( $fh, 1024 * 8 ) );
                        flush();
                    }
                    @fclose( $fh );
                }
            }
            exit();         
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Good answer, just one suggestion for improvement: You should not transform the whole $_POST array to a string.
It's better to always be explicit in this case. You can use array_intersect_key for example: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php#109706

Comment: indeed - plenty of ways to alter this but rather than the mechanism used to assign post content to the csv it is the headers that are particularly relevant to the OPs requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all I had to put was this chunk of code
it works

```
 if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $str=implode( ',', $_POST );
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=mycsv.csv');
    exit( $str );
   }
```